# TS Reverse boolean sort

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting, boolean

I have got a problem with boolean sort
I have this function

```
sortExt() {
    this.usersChoose.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.EXT - b.EXT
    })
}
```

Call with this btn

```
<button class="btn btn-info" (click)="sortExt()">Filter</button>
```

I want reverse my sort like this

```
sortExt() {
    this.usersChoose.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.EXT - a.EXT
    })
}
```

But i don't know what I can do it
Thanks

Comment: After button click, what should happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "boolean sort"? And it's also unclear about "when i can do it"

Comment: Now when I click, my table sorts with the boolean at the beginning and I want that in the future click it will sort in the other direction

Comment: Type of `EXT` is boolean? Also, please add some sample data to work with. At the moment, we don't have any idea of what you're trying to achieve here, what's the data you're working with and why you doing what you're trying to do. Some background about that would really help.

Comment: This is an example of my array

Comment: data=[
{
 "fullName":"toto",
 "EXT":true,
 },
 {
 "fullName":"tutu",
 "EXT":true,
 },
 {
 "fullName":"titi",
 "EXT":false,
 }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution, i have update my function like this. I don't know if it's the best solution but it's work.

```
  sortExt(order) {
    this.usersChoose.sort(function(a, b) {
      if(order == "asc") {
        return (a.EXT === b.EXT)? 0 : a.EXT ? -1 : 1;
      } else {
        return (a.EXT === b.EXT)? 0 : a.EXT ? 1 : -1;
      }
    })
    if(order == "desc") {
      document.getElementById('filterIntExt').addEventListener("click", (e:Event) => this.sortExt('asc'));
    } else {
      document.getElementById('filterIntExt').addEventListener("click", (e:Event) => this.sortExt('desc'));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sortExt() {
this.usersChoose.sort(function(a, b) {
  // true values first
    return (a.EXT === b.EXT)? 0 : a.EXT ? -1 : 1;
 // false values first
 // return (a.EXT === b.EXT)? 0 : a.EXT ? 1 : -1;
})}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this answer will solve the problem, instead of posting code-only answer.

Comment: This answer don't solve the problem, how I can toggle my event for when I click one time execute this return `a.EXT - b.EXT` and the second time when I click execute this return `return b.EXT - a.EXT`